# How to make custom header/footer, marginnotes and use custom fonts in "memoir"?

Tags: header-footer, color, memoir, fontspec, marginnote

I'm new to LaTeX. I'm using *XeLaTeX* on *Linux Mint Tara* to compile. Updated version of *TeX Live* is installed.

**Here's What I'm trying to make:**
[image: LaTeX_Layout_Goal]

**Here are my queries:**

1. I have used `fontspec` package to change the fonts but is there a way to do it without additional packages?
2. How to make margins in `memoir`? I used `\setulmarginsandblock{2cm}{*}{1}` but it is including the header I think.
3. How to make headers, footers without `fncyhdr` package? Documentation of `memoir` asks to use `\makeevenhead` & `\makeoddhead` but my book has `oneside`. How to edit my Header/Footer?
4. The header I need is *multi-lined*; First line is just centered aligned plaintext followed by `\makeheadrule`;
5. Chapter number includes section number;
   `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` are both on left side with `/` between them.
   One is `\textbf{}` other is not. Both are italicized.
6. Right side of header contains `\textbf{Page | }` followed by page numbering that includes ChapterNumber with chapterwise pagenumber[**2-18/35**] indicating the follows,
   **2**=*Current Chapter Num*;
   **18**=*Current Page Num*;
   **35**=*Total Pages in Current Chapter*.
7. The footer is just
   `\FAS{"F0E0} \textbf{Mail: }\textit{abcxyz@isro.in}\hfill\FAB{"F16D} \textbf{Mail: }\textit{abcxyz@isro.in}\hfill\FAS{"F57D} \textbf{Website: }\textit{www.isro.gov.in}`
   between *two footrules* `\makefootrule` I guess?? How to change header/footer to Aqua? `\aqt`?
8. Lastly, how to make SideMarginNotes that aligns with top of a paragraph?? Whose width is *5cm*? I tried `\setmarginnotes{17pt}{5cm}{0}` from `memoir` docs but it doesn't work. How to add text or figure or table to it with heading & captions?

Here's my code so far...

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,showframe]{memoir}

    \setlrmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2cm}{*}
    \setulmarginsandblock{2cm}{*}{1}
    \checkandfixthelayout


    \chapterstyle{bianchi}

    \usepackage{blindtext}

    \usepackage{xcolor}
        \makeatletter
            \newcommand{\globalcolor}[1]{%
                \color{#1}\global\let\default@color\current@color
            }
        \makeatother
        \AtBeginDocument{\globalcolor{white}}

        \definecolor{sectioncolour}{RGB}{0,255,255}
        \definecolor{chaptercolour}{RGB}{0,255,255}
        \definecolor{subsectioncolour}{RGB}{0,255,255}

        \setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\color{sectioncolour}}
        \setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\color{subsectioncolour}}

        \renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont\large\scshape\raggedleft\color{chaptercolour}}
        \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\Huge\bfseries\color{chaptercolour}}
        \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\sffamily\raggedleft\color{chaptercolour}}

    \usepackage[pages=all]{background}
        \backgroundsetup{
            scale=1,color=black,opacity=0.10,angle=0,contents={
                \includegraphics[height=15cm]{draft.png}
            }
        }

        %\setmainfont{Ubuntu}
        %\setmonofont{Ubuntu Mono}
        %\newfontface{\fasfont}{Font Awesome 5 Free Solid}
        %\NewDocumentCommand{\FAS}{m}{{\normalfont\fasfont\symbol{#1}}}

        %\newfontface{\farfont}{Font Awesome 5 Free Regular}
        %\NewDocumentCommand{\FAR}{m}{{\normalfont\farfont\symbol{#1}}}

        %\newfontface{\fabfont}{Font Awesome 5 Brands Regular}
        %\NewDocumentCommand{\FAB}{m}{{\normalfont\fabfont\symbol{#1}}}


    \begin{document}
    \BgThispage
    \pagecolor{darkgray}

    \Blinddocument

    \Blinddocument

    \end{document}
```

Here's what my code gives me:
[image: ObtainedLayout]
[image: Footer Text]

Sorry for such a long question... Thanks if you read it till the end.

Comment: (2) it does not, (3) oneside only uses the design of XoddX.

Comment: (2) In the pdf I'm not getting 2cm top margin...

Comment: It is exactly 2cm, `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,showframe]{memoir}

\setlrmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2cm}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout

\pagestyle{showlocs}

\usepackage{tikz,xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[red,opacity=0.5] (current page.north west) rectangle
  ($(current page.north east) +(0,-2cm)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
`

Comment: The 2cm is from the top of the paper to the top of the textblock.

Comment: Why isn,t `\makeoddhead{mystyle}{\bfseries\leftmark\hspace{5pt}/\hspace{5pt}\itshape\rightmark}{}{\bfseries Page | \itshape\thepage}` working? \leftmark isn't getting printed...

Comment: Under oneside memoir will only write to rightmark (this can be changed)

Comment: Can I use `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark` instead?

Comment: Those are setter macros, not getters (`\leftmark` and `\rightmark` are "getters"). You can try `        \makeatletter
        \addtopsmarks{mystyle}{}{
          \createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ }
          \createmark{section}{both}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
        }
        \makeatother` you might not want to have `both` on both chapter and section, at the same time, it can get `both`, `left`, `right`